# How to change product price with Plugin in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, catalog-product

How to change product price with Plugin in Magento 2 after saving product ?

Comment: In front end or backend?

Comment: in magento backend

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can help for this functionality - https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-change-product-price-with-plugin-magento-2.html